# Unable to load initramfs on my x86 board

Tags: linux

I am currently working on x86 board. I copied my kernel and initramfs to /boot directory 
    and called grub2-mkconfig. once I reboot I am able to run my Linux-kernel. 
    but it is unable to load file system. Giving below error.

```
Starting init: /sbin/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)
[    3.891726] request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-464c
[    3.900455] Starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it   (error -8)
[    3.908356] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.

 /sbin/init files are there in my filesystem.
```

Comment: Is the `/sbin/init` file marked as executable? this is what the `-8` error means.

Comment: Hi Petesh i changed the permissions of the whole filesystem to executable.

Comment: Did you build a 32bit kernel and use 64bit binaries? This is a strong hint when you see the `binfmt-464c` modprobe error on kernel startup.

Comment: Thanks Petesh, Problem resolved. I compiled my kernel as 32-bit and trying to use my filesystem which is 64 bit